# include 2 fragments inside one activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments: `ls_fragment` and `pm_fragment`. I'm trying to show the `pm_fragment` in the portrait mode and both fragments in the landscape mode, but my code doesn't work as well. In the portrait mode it works and show `pm_fragment`, but in the landscape mode it shows only one fragment(the `lm_fragment`).

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        LM_Fragment lm_fragment = new LM_Fragment();
        PM_Fragment pm_fragment = new PM_Fragment();

        /**
         * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
         */
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            /**
             * Landscape mode of the device
             */
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, lm_fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
          //fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
        }else{
            /**
             * Portrait mode of the device
             */
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

and `LM_Fragment` class (looks like `PM_Fragment` class):

```
public class LM_Fragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Inflate the layout for this fragment
         */
        return inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <framelayout
        android:name="com.example.myfragments.LM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <framelayout
        android:name="com.example.myfragments.PM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

lm_fragment.xml(look like pm_fragment.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7bae16">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/landscape_message"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20px" />

    <!-- More GUI components go here  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

how can I show both of fragment in landscape?

Comment: Use FrameLayout Instead of Fragment and replace the fragment in fragment container from cs file

Comment: Probably due to weight. try it by adding weightsum=1 in LinearLayout and give `android:layout_weight` .3 to first Fragment and .7 to second

Comment: Because of the weighting issues and trying to get it right, would you not be better to use RelativeLayout and divide the screen into equal halves for each FrameLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your activity_main.xml with following code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <framelayout
        android:name="com.example.myfragments.LM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/lm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <framelayout
        android:name="com.example.myfragments.PM_Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/pm_fragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```